# Distributing extension module as source with setuptools

Tags: python, setuptools

I'm testing distributing a Python extension module as an egg created with setuptools.
Here is my setup.py script:

```
from setuptools import setup, Extension

setup(
    name = "Hello",
    version = "0.1.0",                      
    ext_modules = [Extension('Hello', ['Source/Hello.cpp'])]
)
```

Then I build the egg with "setup.py bdist_egg" and install it with easy_install.
Everything works. There is one problem though.

The source is compiled when I run "setup.py bdist_egg" and the egg contains the pyd.
However, I want to create an egg that contains the source, and the source to be compiled when the user installs the egg.
How should I change the setup script?

Comment: bdist is short for binary distribution, I'm not sure if a source distribution can be an egg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Janne Karila's comment cleared away my confusion:

```
bdist = binary distribution
sdist = source distribution
bdist_egg = binary distribution as egg
```

There is no sdist_egg.

Answer (score 1):

You create a source distribution: `python setup.py sdist`, which creates a compressed snapshot of your tree. This can then be installed with easy_install.

Better though, if you want to distribute the source publicly, is to use the [python package index](http://pypi.python.org/pypi), following the docs [here](http://diveintopython3.ep.io/packaging.html).